# iOS UI specs to all devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uikit, responsive

In general, we receive UI specs of a device from design team. Is there any automated tool which could provide me the relevant numbers for all the devices?

**e.g.** Design team provides specs of iPhone6, and in that, there exists a view with height **h** px, width **w** px, space between two vertical view elements **s** px. Now, applying these same specs to all devices are ruining the UI across the devices.

So, How could I generate the specs to iPhone plus, iPad mini, iPhone5S, iPad, iPad pro. Pls note that, unlike few years back, the aspect ratio of Apple devices are not the same now

Comment: Use `autolayout` to manage UI for all screensize. If you don't have idea about autolayout then refer this tutorials from [Raywendrlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) and [Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/) Hope this will help :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/ The Magical world

Comment: Auto layout is ur solution!